# The crowd _____(was/were) dispersed by the police

Tags: grammar, nouns, grammatical-number, tenses

Here, the people comprising the crowd are dispersing in different directions, right? So, the word 'crowd' is no longer a singular unit.

Kindly, someone confirm the answer.

Comment: One way I like to think about question like these is: Did the police disperse the crowd, or disperse the people in the crowd? They dispersed the crowd, not the people, so the verb should be singular. And [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crowd+was+dispersed%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Ccrowd+were+dispersed%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) agrees. But I don't think any British people would even notice (let alone think you were committing a great offense against the English language) if you said "were dispersed" and not "was dispersed."

Comment: @PeterShor: True, dat. For most of us Brits, the "crowd" is likely to be ***singular*** if we're seeing it from the police's perspective (it's a "blob" of potential trouble that they need to deal with), but ***plural*** if we sympathize more with the protesters, and see the crowd as a large number of people making their point (where *in our imagination*, we could have perhaps been one of the crowd ourselves).

Comment: ... Yes, 'were' makes it more personal, less clinical.